# How to fix data which is entered from an Excel to WebPage

Tags: java, excel, selenium

I am using an ExcelUtil to enter CompanyID as it is suppose to be unique all the time. When I run the below code, all details are getting filled perfectly fine except CompanyID which is having 2 decimals.

I am expecting it to be `1002` but it is coming as `1002.00`

I have checked my Excel info/Options/Advance and also formatted the cell to General but it is still picking decimal points I don't know why?

```
int i = 1;
while (i < 100) {
    //This goes to 1st row and read the status column if it is Done mark, it is going to move to next
    String status = ExcelUtil.getCellData(i, 4);
    if (status.equals("Done")) {
        i++;
        System.out.println("ComapnyID already exits");
    } else {
        //here it finds the CompanyID which has not been used and send the row number
        companyPage.companyIDExcel(ExcelUtil.getRowData(i));
        ExcelUtil.setRowNumber(i);
        break;
    }
}
//here it is sending the row data to webpage
companyPage.newCompanyID(ExcelUtil.getRowData(i));
```

Comment: Format `CompanyID` field as text, and then give a try.

Comment: Thanks that worked